# How to use sharpziplib in Monotouch?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, sharpziplib

Hi I need to unzip a file in Monotouch for an iOS (and Andriod later) App and sharpziplib looks like a good choice (is it?). But how do I go about adding it in MonoDevelop (I have the latest version)?

I have downloaded ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll, but how/where is it added to my project (solution)? Can anyone give me step-by-step instructions?

Also which .net version of the DLL should I be using? There are three: net-11, net-20, netcf-20 (i think it's the last one but would be good to have that confirmed).

Comment: You can't use a binary dll built for the full .NET framework with MT.  You need to build it from source using the MT compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a MonoTouch class library project for ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib and add the corresponding source files to that project.

Then you can either reference the resulting assembly or the project itself in your solution.